# Excel Define a range based on a cell value (column wise - A to E )

Tags: excel, range, cell

So, for example: My selection is A1:E1 That are five cells. is it possible to let excel determine this by setting a cell value (like A2) to 5.

It for the purpose of easily changes a lot of ranges with one change in a cell value. So if I would change the cell value (A2) to 6. The range would automatically change to A1:F6

Could somebody help me???

Comment: Might it not be better to have Excel automatically adjust to the range?  Something like `=$A$1:INDEX($1:$1,,COUNTA($1:$1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula

> ="=A1:"&ADDRESS(A2,A2,4)

Comment: You might be having value 2 in cell B1.

Comment: By this formula my output is A1:B2, but I want A1:B1

Comment: @Karan then if you have value as 6 it will show A1:F1

Comment: @karan that will give you A1:A6 when you have value 6 in A2 , in general first parameter in address will change row and the second will change column.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my comment you can use INDEX to return the range you're after.

This will use B1 to determine the last cell in the range.

```
=$A$1:INDEX($1:$1,,$B$1)
```

This will then sum the values in that range:

```
=SUM($A$1:INDEX($1:$1,,$B$1))
```